# MySQL Partitions Optimisation (with prunining)

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, database-partitioning

we have a partitioned table with 15 days worth of data at about 200,000,000 rows. (Day 16 is dropped & day 0 created each morning.)

The table is often exceedingly fast but sometimes it can be exceedingly slow and I'm wondering if anyone has any tips for discovering the problem/bottleneck.

The table is partitioned by list on 'day' (using a 'day-of-epoch' integer; today =~ 15100 ) and sub partitioned by linear key another important id.  Both day & id make up part of the primary key, in the right order and are used in the queries.

A typical query might use only 6 of the 360 partitions (via pruning).

What's got me stumped is that while it often runs at ~350+ queries per second it sometimes slows to 2 qps for the same query... and will take minutes to pull 100 queries.

Completely restarting MySQL doesn't seem to affect the arbitrary difference in speed between two similar queries, which makes me think that the problem must be related to disk IO & disk caching?

Question really is; where does one start looking? MySQL, bonnie++? ..

Thanks!

Comment: Just an opinion: Have a look at slow-query-log (activate it if it is not already active, and find slow queries and run explain on them maybe the problem is some missing indexes or something like that)http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for getting back to me.. I have, yes.  What it shows is that these little queries can run at about (avg) 2 seconds a piece [eg: # Query_time: 4.927696  Lock_time: 0.000087 Rows_sent: 489  Rows_examined: 489] but as often as not it will complete 300 of the same queries in < 1 second. Weird?

Comment: A few questions. How long does it slow down for? Which OS is it running on? Do any other tasks the OS is running have an activity spike when MySQL slows down, or is all the reduction in speed down to MySQL? Could it be a garbage collection is running or something.

Comment: @Jaydee I've been trying with just the raw queries in terminal with SQL_NO_CACHE included.  With the OS doing little or nothing else the queries can still be very slow (>2.5s) the first time.  Running them again they're then <0.005s.  If I repeat the query changing the ID in the WHERE (so forcing it to look in 6 other partitions) then we're back to a slow first query. If the SQL_CACHE is being explicitly disabled then does this mean that the speed is down to a disk IO problem loading the indexes for the partitions?  (Explain: RANGE, PRIMARY, keylen=8, partitions=6, rows= ~600).

Comment: [Partition Key Distribution Chart/Data](http://twitpic.com/63wv74/full) - a quick summary of the partition key-distribution.  170 partitions in total, indices average 25MB, full table's index is 4GB... is it just a disk IO problem?

Comment: You can view how MySQL utilizes partitions in a query execution by using EXPLAIN PARTITIONS instead of the simple EXPLAIN statement. Also, perhaps IO is intermittently changing on the server. If you are on Linux, you can use the iostat utility to monitor disk IO.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth; we've changed hardware & upgraded MySQL 5.1->5.5 and the problem has disappeared.  Unfortunately since both are a big step I couldn't be certain which was the fix.